# Want to show null values in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have this sentence in DAX:
DEFINE

```
MEASURE 'BUYING SHOP'[FromDate] =

    CALCULATETABLE (

        DATEADD ( 'BUYING SHOP'[FROM_DATE], -1, YEAR ),

        KEEPFILTERS ( TREATAS ( { @sadCode }, 'BUYING SHOP'[SAD_CODE] ) )

    )

MEASURE 'BUYING SHOP'[ToDate] =

    CALCULATE (

        [Prior Completed Month],

        KEEPFILTERS ( TREATAS ( { @sadCode }, 'BUYING SHOP'[SAD_CODE] ) )

    )

MEASURE 'PRODUCT'[Maintenance_Repair] =

    CALCULATE (

        SUMX (

            FILTER (

                PRODUCT,

                PRODUCT[PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE] = "MAINTENANCE_AND_REPAIR"

            ),

           PURCHASE[Sum Purchases Prior]

        )

    )
```

EVALUATE

SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (

```
'DATE'[cMonth],

KEEPFILTERS ( TREATAS ( { @sadCode }, 'BUYING SHOP'[SAD_CODE] ) ),

KEEPFILTERS (

    FILTER (

                ALL ( 'DATE'[FullDate] ),

                'DATE'[FullDate] >= 'BUYING SHOP'[FromDate]

                    && 'DATE'[FullDate] <= 'BUYING SHOP'[ToDate]

            )

),



"Maintenance_Repair", [Maintenance_Repair]

)
```

ORDER BY 'DATE'[cMonth] ASC

that returns this table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkYiJ.png)

What I want is that all months appear in the table even if it does not have any record.
for example:
03-Mar 20.8
*04-Apr 0*
05-May 222.04
*06'Jub 0*

and goes like that
Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your measure to add zero.

```
MEASURE 'PRODUCT'[Maintenance_Repair] =

    CALCULATE (

        SUMX (

            FILTER (

                PRODUCT,

                PRODUCT[PRODUCT_CATEGORY_CODE] = "MAINTENANCE_AND_REPAIR"

            ),

           PURCHASE[Sum Purchases Prior]

        )

    ) + 0
```

Comment: Hi, I`m a bit lost. How do I change it?

Comment: Literally just + 0 to the end of your measure as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: I haven't seen that 0 at the end
 It worked perfectly